# Angularjs routing matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

In one of my view ther is a link like this with href attribute href = "!#/Program"and i am trinying to match it with below routing,but its giving me no route matches error as "No route matches "/!".

my html code is

```
<p><a href="!#/Program">Click me</a></p>
```

my main.js file

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
         app.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
        //$locationProvider.hashPrefix("!") ;
        $routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        templateUrl: "app.html",
        controller: "AppCtrl"
    }

)
    .when('/Program' ,
    {   templateUrl: "detail1.html" ,
        controller: "Redirect"
    }
)
    .when('/Program/123456/channel/78458585',

    {
        templateUrl: "details.html" ,
        controller: "Detail"
    }
    )  ;
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the path without the `bang(!)`, try this:

```
<p><a href="#/Program">Click me</a></p>
```

If you set `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');`, then you should use `#!` in stead of `!#` like this (make sure you have the module `$locationProvider` injected)

```
<p><a href="#!/Program">Click me</a></p>
```

`#` is the separator, and the ***prefix*** is inserted at the beginning of the `#` part which is after `#`.